# Best model weights in neural network in case of early stopping

Tags: keras, neural-network, early-stopping

I am training a model with the following code

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu',input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=3)
model.fit(X_train_np,target,validation_split=0.3, epochs=100, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])
```

This is designed to stop the training if the val_loss: parameter does not improve after 3 epochs. The result is shown below. My question is will the model stop with weights of epoch 8 or 7. Because the performance got bad in epoch 8 so it stopped. But the model went ahead by 1 epoch with a bad performing parameter as earlier one (epoch 7) was better. Do I need to retrain the model now with 7 epochs?

```
Train on 623 samples, validate on 268 samples
Epoch 1/100
623/623 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 4.0365 - accuracy: 0.5923 - val_loss: 1.2208 - val_accuracy: 0.6231
Epoch 2/100
623/623 [==============================] - 0s 114us/step - loss: 1.4412 - accuracy: 0.6356 - val_loss: 0.7193 - val_accuracy: 0.7015
Epoch 3/100
623/623 [==============================] - 0s 103us/step - loss: 1.4335 - accuracy: 0.6260 - val_loss: 1.3778 - val_accuracy: 0.7201
Epoch 4/100
623/623 [==============================] - 0s 106us/step - loss: 3.5732 - accuracy: 0.6324 - val_loss: 2.7310 - val_accuracy: 0.6194
Epoch 5/100
623/623 [==============================] - 0s 111us/step - loss: 1.3116 - accuracy: 0.6372 - val_loss: 0.5952 - val_accuracy: 0.7351
Epoch 6/100
623/623 [==============================] - 0s 98us/step - loss: 0.9357 - accuracy: 0.6645 - val_loss: 0.8047 - val_accuracy: 0.6828
Epoch 7/100
623/623 [==============================] - 0s 105us/step - loss: 0.7671 - accuracy: 0.6934 - val_loss: 0.9918 - val_accuracy: 0.6679
Epoch 8/100
623/623 [==============================] - 0s 126us/step - loss: 2.2968 - accuracy: 0.6629 - val_loss: 1.7789 - val_accuracy: 0.7425
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `restore_best_weights` with `monitor` value set to target quantity. So, the best weights will be restored after training automatically.

```
early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=3, 
                                       monitor='val_loss',  # assuming it's val_loss
                                       restore_best_weights=True )
```

From docs:

> restore_best_weights: whether to restore model weights from the epoch with the best value of the monitored quantity (`'val_loss'` here). If `False`, the model weights obtained at the last step of training are used (default `False`).

[Docmentation link](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping)

Comment: This does not apply to the main topic. But you may want to use `ModelCheckpoint` to save weights during training. Also, the training curve is quite unstable, so check learning rate value etc.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot :) I will take your suggestion, what did you observe in the result which made you say that the curve is unstable?

Comment: @jyotiska these graphs does not decreasing epoch by epoch: val loss  ...0.71, 1.38, 2.73, 0.59...; and train loss ...1.44, 1.43, 3.57, 1.31.... I don't know it is due to relatively small dataset size or the reason is high learning rate (so the model ca't stop in local minima).

Answer (score 0):

> All the code that I have placed is in TensorFlow 2.0

- **file path:** Is a string that can have formatting options such as the epoch number. For example the following is a common filepath (weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5)
- **monitor:** (typically it is‘val_loss’or ‘val_accuracy’)
- **mode:** Should it be minimizing or maximizing the monitor value
  (typically either ‘min’ or ‘max’)
- **save_best_only:** If this is set to true then it will only save the 
  model for the current epoch, if it’s metric values, is better than
  what has gone before. However, if you set save_best_only to
  false it will    save every    model after each epoch (regardless of
  whether that model was better than previous models or not).

Code

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu',input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
fname = "weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(fname, monitor="val_loss",mode="min", save_best_only=True, verbose=1) 
model.fit(X_train_np,target,validation_split=0.3, epochs=100, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```